# SQL Join tables - join with last four digits of columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I'm trying to join two tables in SQL. I want to join on the column with the last four digits of a phone number with the a column from a second column where only the last four digits are shown.

```
From ExcelSheet1 E
Join Walkers W
ON W.Lastname = E.LNAME
AND W.Firstname = E.FNAME
and W.PhoneNum like '%'+E.MEMBER_NUM
```

Comment: Assuming `MEMBER_NUM` is a `(N)VARCHAR` that query is ok, what's the problem you're having?

Comment: What's the problem then? What is not working?

Comment: It was of type float. So casting it as a varchar fixed the problem

Comment: Then presumably you would have been getting an error, something about unable to convert varchar to float...

Answer (score 0):

```
From ExcelSheet1 E
Join Walkers W
ON W.Lastname = E.LNAME
AND W.Firstname = E.FNAME
and W.CardNum like '%'+ cast(E.MEMBER_NUM as varchar)
```

after casting the variable MEMBER_NUM as a varchar i got the result i was looking for